# How to access Struct field dynamically

Tags: solidity

I have a struct

```
    struct lineItem {
        string idNo;
        string date;
        string code;
        string docCode;
        string vendorNumber;
        string invoiceDate;
        string typeOfTransaction;
    }
```

I have a mapping

```
    mapping(string => lineItem[]) lineItems;//here string will be the user who adds data to this
```

So i have to filter the mapping according to the username given and after that i have to filter those data having idNo same as the input

```
      function getByInternalDocNo(string memory creator,string memory docNo,string memory typeOfFilter) public view returns(lineItem[] memory,vatDetails[] memory){
        uint count = 0;
        // bool[] memory res = new bool[](lineItems[creator].length);
        for (uint index = 0;index<lineItems[creator].length;index++){
            if(keccak256(bytes(lineItems[creator][index].idNo))==keccak256(bytes(docNo))) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        lineItem[] memory res1 = new lineItem[](count+1);
        vatDetails[] memory res2 = new vatDetails[](count+1);
        count = 0;
        for (uint index = 0;index<lineItems[creator].length;index++){
            if(keccak256(bytes(lineItems[creator][index].idNo))==keccak256(bytes(docNo))) {
                res1[count] = lineItems[creator][index];
                res2[count] = vatDetail[creator][index];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return (res1,res2);
    }
```

Now i want to make this function a bit more generic for all type of filters i.e. to check whether coCode is equal to given value or not.So,i wanted to do something like this

```
lineItems[creator][index][typeOfFilter]// will give error
```

and use this to compare it with the input value.So how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

well, given that all the members of your struct are of the same type, `string`, one way to do it would be to use an `enum` and an array of strings:

```
enum fields {idNo, date, code, docCode, vendorNumber, invoiceDate, typeOfTransaction}
struct lineItem {
   string[8] data;
}
```

then you can do

```
function getByInternalDocNo(string memory creator,string memory docNo, fields typeOfFilter) public view returns(lineItem[] memory,vatDetails[] memory){
```

and

```
lineItems[creator][index].data[uint256(typeOfFilter)];
```

note that you do need to manually cast the enum to a uint.

Comment: I'm sending the args ["abc","1221","idNo"],for which it is throwing error INVALID_ARGUMENT

Comment: enums are a user-friendly way of representing (usually) an ordered list of numbers.  So in my example code `idNo` is actually the integer `0`, `date` is `1`, `code` is `2` etc..

so you need `["abc","1221",0]` for your example

depending on which language you're using you may be able to recreate the enum to make the code look more similar.

if you *really* wanted to use an actual string here, you'll need to do some sort of lookup.  I'd strongly recommend doing that off chain, although it would be possible, if expensive, on-chain.  what language are you using to call solidity?